# Formatting MongoDB result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

MongoDB return the following JSON array when we fetch data from collection "Articles"

```
[{
    "_id": "id1",
    "description": "Description for article",
    "author": "publisher of article"
}, {
    "_id": "id2",
    "description": "Description for article",
    "author": "publisher of article"
}, {
    "_id": "id3",
    "description": "Description for article",
    "author": "publisher of article"
}]
```

However I want json in following format

```
[{
    "id1": {
        "_id": "id1",
        "description": "Description for article",
        "author": "publisher of article"
    },
    "id2": {
        "_id": "id2",
        "description": "Description for article",
        "author": "publisher of article"
    },
    "id3": {
        "_id": "id3",
        "description": "Description for article",
        "author": "publisher of article"
    }
}]
```

Is it possible to attain such result using MongoDB query?

Comment: Why would you want to format it like that?

Comment: In order to fetch the result directly by specifying the key instead of looping through the JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [map reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/) :

- map function :

  ```
  var mapFunction = function() {
      var obj = {};

      obj[this._id] = {

          "_id": this._id,
          "description": this.description,
          "author": this.author

      };
      emit(1,obj);
  };
  ```
- reduce function :

  ```
  var reduceFunction = function(key, values) {

      var reduced = {};

      var output_arr = [];

      values.forEach(function(value) {
          Object.keys(value).forEach(function(key) {
              var obj = {};
              obj[key]=value[key];
              output_arr.push(obj);
          });
      });

      reduced["data"] = output_arr;

      return reduced;

  };
  ```

The map reduce query :

```
db.items.mapReduce(mapFunction, reduceFunction, { out: { inline: 1 } })
```

You can access the results in `results[0].value.data`. Output is :

```
{
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "value" : {
                "data" : [
                    {
                        "id1" : {
                            "_id" : "id1",
                            "description" : "Description for article",
                            "author" : "publisher of article"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id2" : {
                            "_id" : "id2",
                            "description" : "Description for article",
                            "author" : "publisher of article"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id3" : {
                            "_id" : "id3",
                            "description" : "Description for article",
                            "author" : "publisher of article"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 11,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 3,
        "emit" : 3,
        "reduce" : 1,
        "output" : 1
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Can this be done using aggregation or project as this query takes lot of time when I run it to fetch large number of records

Comment: No not for now (mongo 3.4) maybe in future release see https://jira.mongodb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SERVER-5947